# dt is not defined in my function but when I delete the function it works?

Tags: python

When I delete pandas() it works fine but when I wrap it it says that 'dt' is not defined but I am defining it with the exec??? Is there something that I don't know about python that I'm doing wrong?

```
    def myFunction():
      exec('dt=relativedelta('+TIME+')')
      print("dt is ", dt)
      dt_today=datetime.date.today()
      START_DATE=pd.to_datetime(dt_today-dt) 
      print("start date is ", START_DATE)

      df['alias'] = np.where((df[NAME] == mylift), myalias, df.alias)
    
      DATA=df.loc[(df.alias.str.contains(ALIAS)) & (df[DATE] <= TODAY) & (df[DATE] >= START_DATE) ].loc[:,[DATE,'record','alias',NAME]]
        if DATA.empty:
            print("Data Frame is empty, check variables in 'dataFrame=df.loc...'"); exit()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./chart.py", line 186, in <module>
    main()
  File "./chart.py", line 72, in main
    myFunction()
  File "./chart.py", line 95, in myFunction
    print("dt is ", dt)
NameError: name 'dt' is not defined
```

Comment: try renaming your function

Comment: Well, what would you want to use `exec` in the first place? That's almost always the sign that you should do things differently - and it seems totally unnecessary here anyway.

Comment: I did, it use to be pandas_init

Comment: where is dt in your function you need to declare dt as a local variable

Comment: why wrap this in this exec statement? just use dt=relativedelta(TIME) no?

Comment: Defining variables with `exec` is undefined behavior.

Comment: @SeaverOlson dt is no where it's declared with exec, even if I declare it as dt='' I will get an error TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.date' and 'str'. But It works fine when I remove the function def myFunction().

Comment: @ThierryLathuille I'm fairly new to python that's the best way I could figure out how to get 'years=1' into dt=relativedelta(years=1) to use to search for in between dates.

Comment: OK, so you should make rather make clear what you are trying to achieve (do you want to change the number of years? Use something else than 'years'? Make that clear, give some well chosen examples of how you would like to use your function, and ask about that.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille ok sorry about that I usually don't ask questions. I see what the problem is now, I'm not accessing global variables outside of that function.

Comment: Your problem is that you tried to do something like `dt=relativedelta(+'TIME'+)`. All you need is `dt=relativedelta(TIME)`. There is no need for you to use `exec` with a literal string. Wherever you do `exec("x")` you can just do `x`

Comment: @Tomerikoo Thanks, I solved it relativedelta takes kwargs , not strings thanks. I answered my own question. Hopefully it helps someone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answers. I figured out all my problems and I hope this post helps someone else.

1. Python has a different way of dealing with scope than other languages. I had to pass arguments in some functions to make things work and add global df in another to fix one of my problems.

```
def myFunction():
     global df
```

2. The 'exec' thing. Well, I didn't realize that relativedelta uses kwargs. So I fixed that by creating a dictionary and passing it. My error was that I was trying to pass a string.

```
dt=relativedelta(**TIME)
```

Answer (score 1):

As some of the comments already indicate, there is no need to use `exec` here in the first place.  However, let me briefly try and explain why it works in the global scope, but not in a function scope.

In short: the error arises because Python thinks that `dt` on line 3 must be a global variable and hence looks for the *global variable* `dt`.  If you run `exec()` outside a function, it defines the global variable `dt` and all is well.  If you run it inside a function, it does *not* define a global variable and the program breaks.

### Locals and Globals

Conceptually, Python stores variables in dictionaries.  You can access these through the functions `globals()` and `locals()`.  For instance, if you run the following code:

```py
def foo(x):
    y = x + 1
    print(globals())
    print(locals())

number = 123
t = 45
foo(number)
```

you will get the output (I am omitting a lot of stuff from the globals dictionary here):

```
{..., 'foo': <function foo at 0x12345678>, 'number': 123, 't': 45}
{'x': 123, 'y': 124}
```

So, *conceptually*, the line `y = x + 1` is translated to `locals['y'] = locals['x'] + 1`.  In the global context (outside a function), a line like `t = 45`, on the other hand, is translated to `globals['t'] = 45`.

So far so good, but what happens if we slightly change the first line in the function `foo` like so:

```py
def foo(x):
    y = x + t
    print(globals())
    print(locals())
```

Python looks at your code and figures that `t` is *not a local variable*!  Hence, this line is translated to `locals['y'] = locals['x'] + globals['t']`.  Note that it assumes that `t` must be global because it is not defined inside `foo`!

### Using `exec`

If you are using `exec("t = ...")` inside `foo`, you run into trouble.  `exec` itself tries to define the variable `t` to be a local variable in `foo`, of course.  But Python does not look inside the string of `exec` and therefore *does not see* that there is a local variable `t`.  Any use of `t` is still translated to `globals['t']` instead of `locals['t']`.

Unfortunately, the internal design of local variables mean that `exec()` cannot really define or change local variables.  Using `exec()` like this will therefore never fully work.  Should you ever really run into a situation where you absolutely need to do something like this, try using `eval()` instead:

```py
def myFunction():
    dt = eval("relativedelta(" + TIME + ")")
    ...
```

However, please note that there is absolutely no need to do so in the current case, as the other commenters have already pointed out.  You can just write:

```py
def myFunction():
    dt = relativedelta(TIME)
    ...
```

There is a very simple rule of thumb that applies here:

*"Whenever you feel like using `exec()` or `eval()`, don't!"*

Comment: This is a very impressive answer, the only thing that bothers me is the suggestion to use `eval`. Either remove it completely, or if you want to keep it for completeness - at least add a sufficient warning about its use

Comment: @Tomerikoo Thanks.  I guess we both agree that using either `eval` or `exec` here is not a good idea (as mentioned several times by commenters and which I tried to capture at the end).  However, I do not think that it is problematic enough in this context to warrant a 'warning' as such, and there might be other legitimate use cases for the use of `eval`/`exec`.  The suggestion to use `eval` is not meant for the actual code at hand, but as an alternative to when `exec` does not work.